# How to recover or reset password of C1-CMS admin?

Tags: c1-cms

In a self-hosted C1-CMS (formerly Composite C1), how can I reset or recover the password? Can the password be viewed or reset somewhere on the server?

(Composite C1 4.3, Build 4.3.5555.25838)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default XML data store, the users and encrypted passwords are stored in: /App_Data/Composite/DataStores/Composite.Data.Types.IUser.xml

If you have another user with a password you know, you can replace the encrypted password string on the account you are trying to access, with the encrypted password from the account you know. Then login and change the password.

Answer (score 2):

I received this answer from the official Orckestra support team (very helpful, although I am not a paying customer, thumbs up!):

You cannot recover the password, but if you have access to the files (or SQL Database, if you migrated data to SQL) you can reset the password:
This should work for sites running on XML data store (default):

1. Edit the file `~/App_Data/Composite/DataStores/Composite.Data.Types.IUser.xml`
2. Locate the xml element for the user you want to reset the password for
3. Change the following two attributes to the shown values:

> EncryptedPassword="hsfIeqkVA5yoMIwzYIx4fWny5GjwNwiM3wA5K+9qCug="
>   PasswordHashSalt="/zgEhlwBe6Vl0HHqMFPxafrtwqlRIGVS"

4. Save the file.

If your site is on SQL, locate the table `Composite_Data_Types_IUser_Published` and put the above shown values into the corresponding columns (EncryptedPassword and PasswordHashSalt).

You should now be able to log in using the password "123456" for the user you changed above. Once in the CMS Console, you can set a new password using the top Tools menu (top right user menu n V5 and later).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a scenario where neither of the suggested methods would work for me. I was able to remedy this by creating a c1 instance locally, creating a user with the same username and the desired password, and then overwriting the password salt and hash from the local site to the one you're locked out of.